# If the standby server is promoted to master, will it work without any replica?

Tags: postgresql, standby

If I have 1 master and 1 standby server, and my master server is down and the standby server is promoted to master. Does my new master work fine without a replica?
Does it act like a standalone server?

Answer (score 1):

Definitely, Your new primary will act like a standalone. If your configuration file is good, you'll even be able to add the old-primary as a new secondary without any restart.

Just be sure your old primary is not running and modifying data or you'll loose some of it!

> If the primary server fails and the standby server becomes the new
>   primary, and then the old primary restarts, you must have a mechanism
>   for informing the old primary that it is no longer the primary. This
>   is sometimes known as STONITH (Shoot The Other Node In The Head),
>   which is necessary to avoid situations where both systems think they
>   are the primary, which will lead to confusion and ultimately data
>   loss.

You may want to read these documentation page :
https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/warm-standby-failover.html